# How to replace default register route with plug in

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nopcommerce

I want to replace default route for recently add product page on `nopcommerce 3.0`.

Now I try to develop `plugin` that contains new `controller` and `new model` to replace controller and model classes for recently add products page(New Products).

But I can't replace default routing for new products.

How can I replace default routing path in `nopcommerce`?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to create a controller (and action) of the same name in your plugin (with a different namespace). Then put a higher priority on your route than nopCommerce's route. I've actually just answered the same question in nopCommerce forum, you can check it here: [Click to read](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/24127/overriding-other-controllers-and-their-routes.aspx)